# Codeigniter - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{'

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm new in codeigniter programming and i'm having some problems with a link to another controller.

i've got an Homepage (home.php) from wich i've to go to another page.

home.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<!-- This is the default home page -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Animania Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application/styles/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application/styles/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application/styles/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application/styles/style.css"> <!-- Gem style -->
    <script src="application/js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script-->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#offerte').DataTable();
        } );

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#curriculum').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#offerte tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca '+title+'" /> ');
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#offerte').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#curriculum tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca '+title+'" /> ');
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#curriculum').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container row">
        <header class="testata" role="banner">
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Inserimento offerta</li>
                    <li>Inserimento CV</li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>   
            </nav>
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <!-- inser more links here -->
                    <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Registrazione</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
    </div>  


    <div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
        <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
            <ul class="cd-switcher">
                <li><a href="#0">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Nuovo account</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cd-login" action="validation.php" method=GET> <!-- log in form -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password" name="password">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Nascondi</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                        <label for="remember-me">Ricordami</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Hai dimenticato la password?</a></p>
                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-login -->

            <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Nascondi</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                        <label for="accept-terms">Accetto i <a href="#0">Termini</a></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Crea account">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

            <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
                <p class="cd-form-message">Hai perso la tua password? Inserisci il tuo indirizzo email. Riceverai un link per la creazione di una nuova password!</p>

                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Errore!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Torna al log-in</a></p>
            </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
            <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Chiudi</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
            <?php
            if ($offers !== FALSE) {
            print('<div>
    <table class="display" id="offerte" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titolo</th>
                <th>Descrizione</th>
                <th>Candidati</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Titolo</th>
                <th>Descrizione</th>
                <th>Candidati</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot><tbody>');
            //for($i = 0; $i < count($offers); $i++){   
                foreach ($offers as $offer){
                    //echo base_url();
                    //$url=base_url('single-offerta')."?idannunci=".$offer->getId();

                    print("<tr>");
                    print("<td>".$offer->getTitolo()."</td>");
                    print("<td>".$offer->getDescrizione()."</td>");
                    //print('<td><a href="'.site_url('Singoff2').'">'.$offer->getPartecipanti().'</a></td>');
                    print('<td>'.anchor('Singoff2', 'Link Text').'</td>');
                    print("</tr>");
                }
                print("</tbody></table></div>");
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'nessuna offerta';
            } ?>

            <!--script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script-->
            <script src="application/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
            <script src="application/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
            <script src="application/js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="application/js/main.js"></script> <!-- Gem jQuery -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Singoff2.php (controller to the other page)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Single-offerta extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library("SingOffFactory");
        //Create a data array so we can pass information to the view
        $data = array(
            "dettagli" => $this->singofffactory->getDettagli()
        );
        //Load the view and pass the data to it
        $this->load->view("Singoff2", $data);
    }
}
```

If i try my link i have the error below:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{' in D:\inetpub\webs\animaniait\manager\application\controllers\Singoff2.php on line 4
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{'

Filename: controllers/Singoff2.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:
```

Now if i try to change the class name in my Singoff.php file i have a 404 error.

Please help me.....i'm going crazy!!

Comment: `Single-offerta` is not a valid class name. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149303/naming-classes-methods-functions-and-variables

Comment: It's clear you need to carefully study the CodeIgniter documentation from start to finish, and do not forget to follow the enclosed tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error. It is line 4 and invalid character `-` - hyphen. Dashes or hyphens are NOT allowed in class names. 
Class name should follow file name, meaning those two need to be exact the same.
Warm advice would be to read full CI documentation. Pay attention on [file naming](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) and [class and method naming](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming). Also, it could be very helpful to read [PHP OOP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

> A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: ^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$.

In your example file should be `Single_offerta.php` and line 4 should be accordingly

```
class Single_offerta extends CI_Controller {
```

If you want to access your URL with `example.com/single-offerta` most efficient way would be to translate uri dashes in `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` [file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php#L54) setting it to `TRUE`:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: How do you mean? You shouldn't have the same error.

Comment: I tryed changing class name in Single_offerta and changing $route['translate_uri_dashes'] to TRUE...nothing happens

Comment: Try one at a time. First change file and class name as I proposed, with `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE` and go to `example.com/index.php/single_offerta` and describe here what happened.

Comment: It has to work. Something other is wrong too, than. Same error or what?

Comment: 404 page not found

Comment: Check if `http://example.com/index.php/single_offerta` and `http://example.com/index.php/single-offerta` are working.

Answer (score 0):

rename your class name `Single-offerta` to something else. avoid using `-` in your class name

Comment: If i try to change the class name i have a 404 error